# Reversing an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Im working through this problem in a javascript book to reverse an array, and I just dont know why this code isnt working. Can someone please explain? This codes supposed to swap the values, but it does nothing to the array.

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    for (let start = 0, end = array.length - 1; start < array.length, end >= 0; start++, end--) {
        let x = array[start];
        array[start] = array[end];
        array[end] = x;
    }
    return array;
}

reverseArrayInPlace(nums);
console.log(nums);
```

Comment: [I wrote this program for my assignment and it doesn’t work.  What do I do now?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If you're simply doing this for an exercise, so be it, but if this is something critical for a production application, an [`array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method does exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need just to check if `start` is smaller then `end`. The other check is superfluous, because before `end` reaches zero, the loop stops.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    for (let start = 0, end = array.length - 1; start < end; start++, end--) {
        let x = array[start];
        array[start] = array[end];
        array[end] = x;
    }
    return array;
}

let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

reverseArrayInPlace(nums);
console.log(nums);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code swaps each pair of elements twice: once when `start < end` and once when `start > end`. In your if statement, you want to change the break condition to `start < end` and not `start < array.length`.

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    for (let start = 0, end = array.length - 1; start < end; start++, end--) {
        let x = array[start];
        array[start] = array[end];
        array[end] = x;


    }
    return array;
}

reverseArrayInPlace(nums);
console.log(nums);
```

Comment: I moved your code into a snippet-- it does not appear to be working as intended as the array is still in the same order when logged.

Comment: I've fixed the code so it properly reverses the array now

Answer (score 0):

As long as the values in the array are integers, you can perform a bit-wise exclusive or (XOR) without the need a a temporary variable. You could also do this with one control variable i.e. `i`. The time complexity will be O(n/2).

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function reverseIntArrayInPlace(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length / 2); i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
    arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = arr[i] ^ arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
    arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(reverseIntArrayInPlace(nums));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want to swap other types, then you will need a temporary variable.

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function reverseArrayInPlace(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length / 2); i++) {
    const tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
    arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = tmp;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(reverseArrayInPlace(nums));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```